# exclude certain files types from require context

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

```
let requireContext = require.context('../scripts', true, /.*/);
```

how can I exclude certain file types for example (any thing with .css or .ejs or .abc extensions)

Comment: Try `/^(?!.*\.(?:css|ejs|abc)$).*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex like this:

```
let requireContext = require.context('../scripts', true, /^(?!.*\.(?:css|ejs)$).*/);
```

---

or if you want to reuse the regex again somewhere else, you can do this:

```
const noEjsCss = /^(?!.*\.(?:css|ejs)$).*/;

let requireContext = require.context('../scripts', true, noEjsCss);
```